# Is it possible to implement a custom root origin in substrate

Tags: origin

I was looking through a way where there a possibility of implementing a custom root origin in substrate.

Comment: What are you trying to archive? Why do you think another root origin will help?

Comment: Well I was exploring stuffs and I came to realise that it can be used to have authorization checks inside priviledged functions and custom access logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some references that you can walk through:

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/src/frame_system/lib.rs.html#788

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/collective/src/lib.rs#L1032

Comment: Thanks a lot this might help with that